# Taking Udacity Operating Systems Course for fun - Mutexes

Tags: c, mutex

I am working on an assignment from Udacity to improve myself with my spare time. I am a bit confused by the assignment as it pertains to Mutexes and the Dining Philosophers problem (a problem that states there are 5 philosophers with 5 forks, if one philosopher is eating and uses the forks of the neighbors, then the neighbors themselves can not eat). I am not doing something right per the assignment:

For instance,  If philosopher 0 is in the process of eating, then either philosopher 2 or 3 can eat concurrently when philosopher 0 is eating , but neither 1 nor 4 can eat at the same time because the forks are used by philosopher 0.

I get the following output:

```
Philosopher 1 is thinking
Philosopher 1 is eating
Philosopher 0 is thinking
Philosopher 3 is thinking
Philosopher 4 is thinking
Philosopher 3 is eating
Philosopher 2 is thinking
Philosopher 1 finished eating
Philosopher 0 is eating
Philosopher 3 finished eating
Philosopher 2 is eating
Philosopher 0 finished eating
Philosopher 2 finished eating
Philosopher 4 is eating
Philosopher 4 finished eating
```

This is from the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

pthread_t philosopher[5];
pthread_mutex_t philosopherForks[5];

void *diningPhilosopher(int n) {

   printf ("Philosopher %d is thinking\n",n);
   pthread_mutex_lock(&philosopherForks[n]);
   pthread_mutex_lock(&philosopherForks[(n+1)%5]);
   printf ("Philosopher %d is eating\n",n);
   sleep(3);
   pthread_mutex_unlock(&philosopherForks[n]);
   pthread_mutex_unlock(&philosopherForks[(n+1)%5]);

   return(NULL);

}

int main() {
   int i;
   for(i=0;i<5;i++)
      pthread_mutex_init(&philosopherForks[i],NULL);

   for(i=0;i<5;i++)
      pthread_create(&philosopher[i],NULL,(void *)diningPhilosopher,(void *)i);

   for(i=0;i<5;i++)
      pthread_join(philosopher[i],NULL);

   for(i=0;i<5;i++)
      pthread_mutex_destroy(&philosopherForks[i]);



return 0;
}
```

Comment: What exactly is wrong with this? Note that threads don't necessarily run exactly in parallel, so as your program shows, it is clearly possible for one thread to grab two mutexes, "eat", and then release them again, before another threads grabs one of those two mutexes.

Comment: Assuming there are 5 philosophers in all, 2 should be able to eat at the same time. My program only allows one philosopher to eat at a time.

Comment: I would add another `printf` that says, "Philosopher x is done". It's not possible to tell how many are eating at the same time without knowing when they finish.

Comment: I added another printf to show the Philosopher X is done: The output is as follows (edited original post).

Comment: Your program allows to eat two philosophers to eat at the same time just fine. If threads 1 and 3 are running first, then thread 1 can lock mutexes 1 and 2, and thread 3 can lock mutexes 3 and 4. But it is not *guaranteed* that this will happen. It is also possible that all threads really run simultaneously, and all get to lock one mutex, and then are deadlocked waiting for the second mutex.

Comment: So 1 and 3 are eating at the same time. When 1 finishes 0 starts, so 0 and 3 are eating at the same time. Then 0 and 2 are eating. Finally 4 has to eat alone. So that part works. I'm pretty sure the code still has the deadlock issue, but you won't see that until you run the philosophers in a loop.

Comment: Any good idea on what I can do to fix the deadlock issue? Thanks!

Comment: The standard solution is each philosopher **takes the lower numbered fork first**. Philosopher 0 takes fork 0, then fork 1. Philosopher 1 takes fork 1, then fork 2. Likewise for philosophers 2 and 3. Those are all fine in your code, because the code takes fork `n` and then fork `n+1`. But now consider philosopher 4. Philosopher 4 takes fork 4, and then fork 0 (because `(n+1)%5` is 0 when `n` is 4). So philosopher 4 is **taking the higher numbered fork first**. So the fix is to compute the two fork numbers, and then take the lower numbered fork first.